# The output size is smaller than input size is a insecure to hash function

Tags: hash, hmac, mac

Why it will be unsafe, and can be break?

Comment: Could you stop flooding with half questions and write a good question with all your needs and aim? What are your risks, attack vectors? Why you are limited to $H$ hash that only the input and output size is known. What else do we know about it? You have a very specific problem and that can be only correctly answerable if you provide all the information.

Comment: I edited your question to mean what by-standers sees it should mean. If you so eagerly seek a lightweight hash or MAC function, I suggest you check out **Gimli** at [csrc.nist.gov](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/lightweight-cryptography/round-2-candidates), it's designed by well-reputed people, it's got a hash function and an authenticated encryption which can be used as a MAC function if you pass an empty plaintext and a static nonce/IV to it.

Comment: @kelalaka I am so sorry about my fault, I just try to know some key knowledge about hash function not related to my specific problem. I do not want to post the whole thing, and I do not know what kind of things I need to offer. Apologize. I am trying to study cryptography

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the HMAC algorithm because you mentioned "hash". For HMAC, it's only required that the hash function be collision-resistant, as forging a HMAC tag implies that finding collision in the underlaying hash function is possible.

You can find reference in the paper "Keying Hash Functions for Message Authentication" by Mihir Bellare, Ran Canetti, and Hugo Krawczyk.

Also note that ever since SHA3 competition, resistance against length-extension attack is a must-have basic capability of new hash functions - that's why you'd see BLAKE2 and Keccek come with their own MAC construction (KMAC for Keccak, I couldn't recall the name for BLAKE2 though). As this is missing in most hash functions back when HMAC was invented, HMAC is designed to handle the length-extension attack by itself without further requirements on the hash function.